# Layers and Sublayers SVG

Tags: java

I have a problem with reading multilayer svg documents. 
I have for example this SVG file

```
<svg>
    <g transform="skewX(20)">
    <g transform="translate(50)">
    <rect widht="200" height="300"/>
    </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

and my program has a problem to solve it. It thinks that there are two inside g elements one with own transform and second with transform of uplayer.
I work with DOM. 
there is a code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HmG0FO7wkcbMJfVpVSGqE0UvYQ9KcaXy

Comment: Please also post the relevant code of yours in the question.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "my program has a problem to solve it".  I don't have a description of the problem you are experiencing, I only have a document and a program.  Those things are not enough to know what you expect, and what you are seeing, and how those things are different.

Answer (score 0):

The initial problem is that you are not using close tags, nor using the shorthand notation for a self-closing tag, which means that the scope of your graphics "g" tags is not specified.

SVG is an XML specification, closing tags is required.  Once you add the closing specifications, your problem will be different, so it doesn't make sense to answer your initial problem until we see where you put your close tags.  Effectively, depending on where you close your tags, you will have a different problem (or have solved your problem!)

Comment: I forgot to write closetags here.